# Diffusion of electromagnetic fields

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electromagnetic-induction, diffusion

In [magnetotelluric method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetotellurics), inside earth EM field has diffusion equation as opposed to wave equation in air.

Physically diffusion of atoms is intuitive. But what does diffusion of EM field mean physically?

Answer (score -1):

Please see the term here:

> A measure of the tendency of a magnetic field to diffuse through a conducting medium at rest; it is equal to the partial derivative of the magnetic field strength with respect to time divided by the Laplacian of the magnetic field, or to the reciprocal of 4πμσ, where μ is the magnetic permeability and σ is the conductivity in electromagnetic units.

Please see the article here:

http://www.maths.dundee.ac.uk/mhd/Pdfs/diffusion.pdf